# What is the best method in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API for performing batch requests?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, api-design

I have a `POST` endpoint for creating a product, but I want to create multiple products in one call instead of calling the end point multiple times.

I want to follow the REST API design best practices.

I found this article regarding Web API Batch support.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata/

Its from 2013 and I haven't found any examples of how to use it in the latest (.NET 6) so I'm not sure if this method is still recommended?

The other option is to use an endpoint that takes a list of products and process them that way.
[In the new ASP.NET Web API, how do I design for "Batch" requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521467/in-the-new-asp-net-web-api-how-do-i-design-for-batch-requests)

How are people doing handling batch calls to a REST API?
What method do you recommended?

Comment: Are you going to be passing data in such a way where you'd need `multipart/mixed`? If not, then the first example is unnecessary. How is the data being posted? JSON array? If so, you simply just make the endpoint define a `[FromBody] IEnumerable<someObject>`.

Comment: If I was going to use the first method I would use the multipart/mixed. Both methods would work, I’m more asking if there is a preferred method when using a REST API.

Comment: Typically for a restful api, you'd do JSON and just pass in an array from the body with a POST or PUT.